# Funcion para sumar una variable al clicar en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy probando de hacer una función que cada vez que le de click a un botón,  sume un valor a una variable, y se muestre por pantalla pero no funciona.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var a = 0;
function myFunction() {
    a = a + 1;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes que meter la salida dentro de la función y mejor usa [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
var a = 0;
function myFunction() {
  a = a + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Las variables que se crean dentro de una función no sirven para el resto del código de a fuera de la función

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var a = 0;
function myFunction() {
    a = a + 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

Comment: En este caso se ha creado la variable `a` fuera de la función... pero el problema esta en la salida o `return`...

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un ejemplo perfecto para implementar un patrón de cerradura (Closure). El código queda encapsulado de forma elegante sin inicializaciones globales.

```js
// closure para contador, inicializa la variable c en 0
var contador = ((c) => () => ++c)(0);

// manejador del evento onClick
var eventoClick = function() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contador();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="eventoClick()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con algo asi:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("demo"));
  a = a + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    }

</script>
```

El problema esta en que no has iniciado el valor a 0, y por eso al intentar hacer la suma, no te rreporta ningún resultado

Comment: el problema no es el inicio del valor 0.. si no la salida estaba fuera de la función